# How to replace second pattern(dot) after pattern(comma) in bash

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed

How do i replace second dot after comma.

this is the closest i could go

```
echo '0.592922148,0.821504176,1.174.129.731' | xargs -d ',' -n1 echo | sed 's/\([^\.]*\.[^\.]*\)\./\1/' | sed 's/\([^\.]*\.[^\.]*\)\./\1/'
```

Output :

```
0.592922148
0.821504176
1.174129731
```

Expected output :

```
0.592922148,0.821504176,1.174129731
```

Comment: By seeing your profile came to know that you have never selected an answer as correct one. IMHO whenever you post a question on SO wait for sometime and you see some answers try to select anyone of them as correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's/\(\.[^.,]*\)\./\1/' -e 't a'
```

See [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/yOSSWZ):

```
s='0.592922148,0.821504176,1.174.129.731'
sed -e ':a' -e 's/\(\.[^.,]*\)\./\1/' -e 't a' <<< "$s"
```

**Details**

- `:a` - label `a`
- `s/\(\.[^.,]*\)\./\1/` - finds and captures into Group 1 a dot, then any 0+ chars other than dot and comma, and then just matches a dot, and replaces this match with the value in Group 1 (thus, removing the second matched dot)
- `t a` - if there was a successful replacement, goes back to the `a` label position in the string.

Comment: You can shorten to a single expression `sed ':a; s/\(\.[^.,]*\)\./\1/; ta'`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I always posted answers with `;`s before, I decided to post one answer with `-e`s, can't I? This is too preferential IMHO.

Comment: I loved this answer and UV'ed it. Looking at the separate expressions it just caught me that you could do it all in one. Both ways are fine.

Comment: @David afaik BSD sed doesn't let you separate labels and branching ops from other expressions with semicolons

Comment: @oguzismail thank you. That's good info. I don't have a BSD `sed` to test with, but I was unaware of that limitation.

Answer (score 2):

While I think the `sed` solution is your best choice, since you have tagged your question with both `sed` and `awk`, an `awk` solution is fairly straight forward as well using `split()` and basic string concatenation. (just not nearly as short) For example you could do:

```
awk -v OFS=, -F, '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        n=split ($i, a,".")
        if (n > 2) {
            s=a[1] "." a[2]
            for (j=3; j<=n; j++)
                s = s a[j]
            $i=s
        }
    }
}1'
```

Where you define the field separator and output field separators as `','`. Then looping over each field, check the return of `split()`, splitting the field into an array on `'.'` into array `a`. If the resulting number of elements is greater than `2`, then put your first two elements back together restoring the first `'.'` in the number, and then simply concatenate the remaining fields. The `1` at the end is the default "print record" to print the updated record.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo '0.592922148,0.821504176,1.174.129.731' |
> awk -v OFS=, -F, '{
>     for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
>         n=split ($i, a,".")
>         if (n > 2) {
>             s=a[1] "." a[2]
>             for(j=3;j<=n;j++)
>                 s = s a[j]
>             $i=s
>         }
>     }
> }1'
0.592922148,0.821504176,1.174129731
```

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` verison:

```
echo '0.592922148,0.821504176,1.174.129.731' | awk  -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {sub(/\./,"#",$i);gsub(/\./,"",$i);sub(/#/,".",$i);print $i}}'
0.592922148
0.821504176
1.174129731
```

It splits the line inn to multiple fields by `,`.  Then replace first `.` to `#`. Then replace rest of `.` to nothing.  Last replace `#` back to `.` and print it.

Edit

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {sub(/\./,"#",$i);gsub(/\./,"",$i);sub(/#/,".",$i);a=a (i==1?"":",")$i}print a}' file
0.592922148,0.821504176,1.174129731
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i believe this is not my expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
echo '0.592922148,0.821504176,1.174.129.731' | 
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    ind=index($i,".")
    if(ind){
      val1=substr($i,1,ind)
      val2=substr($i,ind+1)
      gsub(/\./,"",val2)
      $i=val1 val2
    }
  }
  val1=val2=""
}
1'
```

---

---

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
echo '0.592922148,0.821504176,1.174.129.731' |   ##Printing values as per OP mentioned and using pipe to send its output as standard input for awk command.
awk '                                            ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                           ##Starting BEGIN section of this program here.
  FS=OFS=","                                     ##Setting FS and OFS as comma for each line of Input_file here.
}                                                ##Closing BEGIN BLOCK here.
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                            ##Starting a for loop to traverse through fields of line..
    ind=index($i,".")                            ##Checking index of DOT in current field and saving it into ind variable.
    if(ind){                                     ##Checking condition if variable  ind is NOT NULL.
      val1=substr($i,1,ind)                      ##Creating variable val1 from sub-string in current field from 1 to ind value.
      val2=substr($i,ind+1)                      ##Creating variable val2 from sub-string in current field from ind+1 value to till complete length of current field.
      gsub(/\./,"",val2)                         ##Globally substituting DOTs with NULL in val2 variable.
      $i=val1 val2                               ##Re-crearing current field with value of val1 val2.
    }                                            ##Closing BLOCK for if condition.
  }                                              ##Closing BLOCK for for loop.
  val1=val2=""                                   ##Nullifying val1 and val2 variables here.
}                                                ##Closing main code BLOCK here.
1'                                               ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited line.
```